# IE hack for javascript & iframe

Tags: javascript

I have a site with URL links on a Links page. Each link takes you to a Frame page that is a big iFrame that pulls in the given URL. I'm using javascript to do this and it works in FF, Safari, Opera and Chrome, but not IE. Does anyone know what I can do to get it to work in IE?

I've built it in WordPress. I have this in Head section between  tags and  tags:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
      function loadIF() { 
      iFrameSrc=location.href.split('?'); 
        if ( iFrameSrc[1] != null ) { 
          document.getElementById('external').src=iFrameSrc[1]; 
          } 
        else { 
          document.getElementById('external').src='default_page.htm' 
          } 
        } 
    </script>
```

Then I put this in header.php as well:

```
    <body onload="loadIF()" <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Here is the link markup:

```
<a href="/frame1?http://www.website.com">Website</a>
```

Thanks-
Chris

Comment: More info would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be splitting the location on the `?` does that mean you are trying to get the parameters?

if so:

```
iFrameSrc = location.search;
if(iFrameSrc)
{
     ... // Code here
}
else
{
    ... // Code here
}
```

or try

```
if(iFrame && iFrame.length > 2)
{
    ... // Code here
}
else
{
    ... // Code here
}
```

**EDIT** ok so after seeing your edit i thought i better add this:

Take the first code example I gave you and replace the first `... // Code here` with:

```
document.getElementById('external').src= iFrameSrc.substr(1); // This will remove the leading question mark.
```

**UPDATE**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function iFrameIF()
        {
            iFrameSrc = location.search;
            if (iFrameSrc) 
            {
                alert(iFrameSrc.substr(1));//document.getElementById('external').src = iFrameSrc.substr(1);
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert(); //document.getElementById('external').src = 'http://about:blank'
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="iFrameIF()">
        <iframe width="100%" height="1000" marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" align="top" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" name="external" id="external"></iframe>
        <br />

    </body>
</html>
```

typing into ie: `file://path/to/file.html?test`  got me an alert saying "test"

Comment: Thanks James, I tried it and now the URLs don't load in any browser. I'm an idiot about javascript... Is this the code that you meant:             <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
  function loadIF() { 
  iFrameSrc = location.search;
if(iFrameSrc)
 { 
      document.getElementById('external').src= iFrame.substr(1); 
      } 
    else { 
      document.getElementById('external').src='default_page.htm' 
      } 
    } 
</script>  --SORRY -- can't figure out how to make this CODE mode...

Comment: i made a typo change `iFrame.substr(1);` to `iFrameSrc.substr(1);`. Sorry!

Comment: My initial thought was that the href was acting different in IE. can you put an alert in to see what the `.src` attribute's value is before setting it?

Comment: `alert(document.getElementById('external').src + " " + iFrameSrc);` put that above the line `document.getElementById('external').src= iFrameSrc.substr(1);` tell me what happens

Comment: OK thanks. In Chrome this pops up: ?http://www.aimsports.com -- But in IE nothing pops up... [Can't figure out how to turn off the link in my comments...please excuse my ignorance...]

Comment: can you add your some of your html markup to your post. I'm grasping at starws here but i'm guessing that there is a markup mistake. (its ok I understand the link fine ;) )

Comment: This is the actual iframe markup:    
            <iframe width="100%" height="1000" marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" align="top" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" name="external" id="external"></iframe>

Comment: James...Do you think I might be better off going with a PHP solution? Originally I had the links on the same page as the frame and just used HTML to get the URL in the frame, and everything was fine in IE...

Comment: @chris i'm not a php guru myself but i definitely think that having php include a partial page or something would be better than having an iframe. i think that wouldbe more robust and flexible. It would also allow you to later add some ajax magic to replace that section for javascript enabled user and degrade nicely for those without.

Comment: OK James...thanks a lot for trying to figure this out for me!!

Comment: @chris i tried a full test and it worked for me. (check my update)

Comment: James, sorry to bother you again..I just came across a thread where someone said onload only works for IE when using the attachEvent method. Their code looked like this: var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "http://google.de";
iframe.attachEvent("onload", function(){
alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
});
document.body.appendChild(iframe);  --------------Do you know if I can apply this to my code? (I realized I probably can't resort to PHP b/c the client needs to be able to make new links to the iframe himself.)

Comment: only if you want to attach it to the iframe `onload` event. it works fin on the body onload. Start with a simple example like the one i posted and then you can add in the extra stuff and find out what is stopping it working.  (also surround your code with ` in comments ;) )

Comment: @chris It just occurred to me: what version of ie are you using?

Comment: I'm testing in IE 7 and IE 8... BUT -- I just set up a test version myself replicating your test and everything works fine in IE! So you're right...something is wrong in my markup. I'm working in wordpress, so maybe I'm doing something wrong there. Well, I'll work on it more and see what I can do. Thanks so much for your troubleshooting...

Comment: @chris to help you we really need more markup. Otherwise we will be guessing in the dark. a good way to test if your onload event is functioning is to change `onload="iframeIF()"` to `onload="alert('loaded!');"`.

Comment: James, thanks to your troubleshooting, I have found the problem. When I removed the following code, everything works in IE: `<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`  Thank you for leading me down the right path!!